# Python: Read in multiple csv files from a directory into a dictionary without using Pandas

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a directory containing multiple csv's that I would to read into a single dictionary. The dictionary would use the original file names as keys and the contents of the csv's as values. I don't want to use pandas because I am new to Python and want to understand these tasks first before pulling out the big guns. I would like to use DictReader for the task. Here is the code I have so far below. It works fine for one file at a time. Help is greatly appreciated.

```
def read_lines():
    data = []
    with open('vari_late_low_scores.csv', newline='') as stream:
        reader = csv.reader(stream, delimiter=',', skipinitialspace=True)
        for row in reader:
            data.append(row)
    return data
```

Thank you!

Comment: When you say 'contents of the csv's as values', what format do you wish these contents to be of?

Comment: Each value would be a list of the rows as if read in individually by csv.reader one at a time.